# how to insert Image a row in DefaultTableModel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

[image]

```
public static void table2() {
    Object num[] = new Object[1];
    for (int q = 0; q < MyDto.userList.size(); q++) {
        try {

            //ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(MyDto.userList.get(q).getMyImg()).getImage()
            //      .getScaledInstance(150, 120, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

             ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("/Users/junseok/Desktop/1.png");
            JLabel lbImage1 = new JLabel(i2);
            lbImage1.setIcon(i2);
            num[0] = lbImage1;
            model2.addRow(num);
            System.out.println(num[0].toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

why doesnt show image? why write only toString()??

Answer (score 0):

> why write only toString()??

The default renderer just invokes the toString() method of the object in the TableModel.

> why doesnt show image?

You need to add an `Icon` to the TableModel (not a JLabel). Then you need to tell the table the Icon is stored in the column so the table can choose the appropriate renderer to paint the Icon.

This is done by overriding the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the TableModel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JPanel
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        Icon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        Icon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        Icon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableIcon());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```